# Const params in routes in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, ngrx

I need to save current selected language in routes.

Example:

```
/en/login
/en/welcome
/ru/register
....
```

Is there a simple way to set some prefix on routes or I should to set lang in each route?

Main idea is write in templates something like

```
[linkTo]="/welcome"
```

But in result in router have something like

```
/en/welcome
```

P.S. I use [ngrx/router](https://github.com/ngrx/router)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a localStorage item which stores the language prefix.
Extend the router and override the navigate mewthod.
When the router is told to navigate, inject the language prefix.

if you dont like the thought of extending the router, make a wrapper, and use the wrapper instead.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyRouter {
    constructor(private _router: Router){}

    navigate(url: string){
        var lang : string = localStorage.getItem("lang");
        this._router.navigate(["/"+lang+"/"+url]);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
import { Router } from "@ngrx/router";
import { LocationStrategy } from "@angular/common";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
@Injectable()
export class GlobalRouter extends Router {
    constructor(public platformStrategy: LocationStrategy) { // ANGULAR 2 DEPENDENCY INJECTOR SHOULD TAKE OVER
    // it's not working
        alert("constructor");
        super(platformStrategy);
    }

    normalize(url: string): string {
        let router = super.normalize(url);
        alert(`normalize router ${router}`);
        return router;
    }
}

bootstrap(AcademyApp, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    provideStore(reducer),
    runEffects(effects),
    connectRouterToStore(),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideDB(schema),
    actions,
    services,
    provideForms(),
    disableDeprecatedForms(),
    FORM_PROVIDERS,
    {
        provide : Router,
        useClass: GlobalRouter
    }
])
```

Comment: Still I have a question. I've create new Router which extend ngrx router. But when I try to provide him, I have an error
*TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBaseHref' of undefined*

Comment: I just put it into bootstrap

    {
  provide : Router,
  useClass: GlobalRouter
    }

Comment: you will need to add : `<base href="/">` into your index.html file, just below the `</head>`

Comment: I have it. I think that problem in injecting.

Comment: if your router is undefined then yes it will be that, do you have the @injectable() decorator or an @Inject() decorator

Comment: try using: 
 `provide{Router,{ useClass: GlobalRouter})`

Comment: 1) It did not help
2) Provide is deprecated

Comment: have you looked at the source to try match and debug you're own? https://github.com/ngrx/router/blob/master/lib/router.ts : function `_getBaseHref(platformStrategy): string {
  const browserBaseHref = platformStrategy.getBaseHref();
  return _stripTrailingSlash(_stripIndexHtml(browserBaseHref));
}` i feel like the problem could be with your LocationStrategy

Comment: What should I debug if I extend this class? I don't understand how provide them.

Comment: I do not set any LocationStrategy myself

Comment: Right now I don't have error. My Router just doesn't working =)
As I could understand, I couldn't extend private field but I use super and override public method. I really couldn't understand why it's not working

Comment: I'm on 100% sure that my problem in injection

Comment: it's working. But I still need to set lang param in each router. I told about pathes which I registered in router